# Boost.TEST with CLion: "Test framework quit unexpectedly"

Tags: c++, clion, boost.test

I am using CLion on mac os mohave. I tried to add Boost.TEST to my c++ project, but the IDE throws "Test framework quit unexpectedly".

Here is my CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(sequences)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(sequences main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(sequences ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY})

enable_testing()
```

And a simple test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test) {
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(1, 1);
}

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Instructions on jetbrains website are bogus about using Boost.TEST and all fixes for this issue I found online are outdated.

I use Boost v.1.67.0 installed with homebrew.

Console output:

Testing started at 09:48 ...
.../sequences --run_test=test --logger=HRF,all --color_output=false --report_format=HRF --show_progress=no
Hello, World!
Process finished with exit code 0

All help and advice are appreciated!

Thanks for help. I ended up creating a template project for tests. I then copy this project into my the project with the actual code and add
add_subdirectory(**name_of_the_directory_with_boost_test_project**) into CMakeFile.

After that you get the "run all test" functionality in CLion.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing or trying to achieve with your code. Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK is a framework for unit tests. It can't work inside your main.cpp

Comment: @ThomasSablik It actually can. However user-provided entry point should properly initialize test framework. See [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/adv_scenarios/entry_point_overview.html).

Comment: @VTT: Yes, of course the tests also need an entry point but it is different from the application's entry point. You need one `main` function for the application and at least one `main` function for the tests.

Comment: @ThomasSablik No, unit tests are not special in any way. Application should have just a single `main` function initializing and running tests, either manually written or provided by boost.

Comment: @VTT: Could you provide an example as answer? I can't imagine how this could work.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Example of user-defined entry point is provided in [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/link_references/link_boost_test_no_main.html).

Comment: @VTT: This user-defined entry point is not the entry point of the application. It is the entry point of the test cases. Can you create an example where application and test cases have the same entry point?

Comment: @ThomasSablik This user-defined entry point `main` is the entry point of the application. Note that function `main` can not be overloaded or invoked, there is no such thing as "entry point of the test cases".

Comment: @VTT: As you can see in your link in the user-defined entry point only test cases are called, no business logic. You create one application with your business logic and at least one application with test cases. I've never seen this mixed up in one application.

Comment: @ThomasSablik What do you mean by "business logic"? You wrote above that *"This user-defined entry point is not the entry point of the application"*, but not you write that "at least one application with test cases". Does this mean that you agree that entry point for unit test is just a regular entry point of the application?

Comment: @VTT: Yes, we mean the same but we use different terms for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program code and your test code should be separated. As stated in [doc](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/adv_scenarios/entry_point_overview.html), the line

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE My Test
```

creates the main entry point.

I don't know if it is possible to write test cases in main.cpp. In unit tests you check the interface of your components.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(sequences)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
add_executable(test1 src/test1.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test_suite1 ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY})

enable_testing()
add_test(NAME test_suite1 COMMAND test_suite1)
```

main.cpp

```
#include "MyMath.h"

int main() {
    MyMath mm;
    mm.add(1,2);

    return 0;
}
```

MyMath.h:

```
#ifndef MY_MATH_H
#define MY_MATH_H

class MyMath {
public:
    int add(int l, int r) { return l + r; }
};

#endif
```

test1.cpp:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE My Test
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include "MyMath.h"
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test) {
    MyMath mm;
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(mm.add(1,2), 3);
}
```

Now I can build it with cmake and test with ctest.

Comment: All right. Basically no main function that does the job. So how do I incorporate boost.test into my existing project that already has libraries and an entry point? And again: I am using CLion. I was lead to understand that it has an integrated test runner for Boost.Test.

Comment: BOOST_TEST_MODULE creates the main entry point for your tests. It is a convention to create a test file for each class.

Comment: @magom001 Unit test project should be a separate project. Typically it is a regular executable project linking (or inlining) boost.test library.

Comment: @VTT I cannot figure out how to do it in CLion. I think something is missing in their documentation: http://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/boost-test-support.html

Comment: @magom001 It looks like clion does not put any special requirements on unit test application. So creating a unit test executable should be similar to creating any other executable in cmake.

Comment: CLion does not support manually registered tests (more precisely: does not support local test configurations and navigation from test result tree for them)